# How to use solr caching effectively having HAProxy for load balancing?

Tags: caching, nginx, solr, haproxy

I have three solr 4.0 servers having HAProxy for load balancing, after going through the solr caching concept, I tuned my document, field and query caching accordingly. But, as the same user can have similar search number of times which if hits a particular server can best utilize the solr caching. Due to HAproxy I think I am not able to use that effectively.

One way is I don't use load balancing and hits same server intentionally  for a user but removing HAProxy will give availability and fault tolerance issues.

I am trying to configure persistence connection on HAProxy for
Solr domain using Session cookie setup by HAProxy itself.But not sure about the impact of same on the over all load. If anyone tried the same would like to know the shortcoming.

So I need suggestions if we have any process to achieve the same in the better way.

Answer (score 0):

if you know repeated searches are going to be very common, then the best gain might be to have a cache you hit before going to the load balanced Solr (Squid, Varnish...whatever).

The lest requests are served without Solr being even aware of them, the better. This way you get the cached results and still have the load balanced setup for the rest (of course you need to check the cache for every request).